# Prove $t^{1\over t-1}$ is rational only when $t=2$ in the context of solving $x^y=y^x$ where $x\neq y$

Tags: exponentiation, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Prove $t^{1\over t-1}$ is rational only when $t=2$ where $t$ is any real number.

This problem arises from me watching the blackpenredpen video solving $x^y=y^x$ where $x\neq y$. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI1NeGtJo7s, in which he gives the solution $x=t^{1\over t-1}$.

First I considered the integer solutions where $x\neq y$ other than $2^4=4^2$ but realized it is trivial because $1<t^{1\over t-1}<2$ for any $t\geq 2$ and $-1>t^{1\over t-1}>-2$ for any $t\leq-2$.

The next question is then, are there any rational solutions other than the $2,4$ pair. It does not seem trivial to me as inequalities do not help.

My guess is that $t^{1\over t-1}$ cannot be rational other than when $t=2$ but I wan't able to prove.

Comment: Over what $t$ are you making the claim? Positive integers?

Comment: Over all real numbers.

Comment: So $t=0$ is possible?

Comment: Then that is not true. The function $f(t) = t^{1/(t-1)}$ is continuous on $(1, \infty)$. Note that $f(2) \neq f(4)$ and so, all the rational values (of which there are infinitely many) between $f(2)$ and $f(4)$ are achieved.

Comment: $t=0$ is possible but that gives $x=y=0$ so $x=y$. What I want is a pair generating $x\neq y$.

Comment: Check your title. Then $t=0$ is a solution different from $2$.

Comment: I edited the title to include the context. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: If over all real numbers surely there are plenty of solutions because $f(x) =  x^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$ is continuous and not very pathological?

Comment: Is it possible to write down a rational solution, or is it just existential without being possible to be written down?

Comment: $t$ can be any real number. I understand now there exists rational solutions but I still want to know can I write one down explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range of $f(t)=t^{1/(t-1)}$ is $(1,\infty)$ and the function is continuous and monotonic, hence invertible. So there is an infinite (but countable) number of solutions of

$$t^{1/(t-1)}=q$$ where $q$ is rational.

---

$$t=-\frac1{\log q}W\left(-\frac{\log q}q\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to write down a rational solution, or is it just existential without being possible to be written down?

Comment: @cr001: possibly in terms of Lambert's $W$ function.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit how to apply the Lambert $W$ function to generate $q$ in order to guarantee $q$ is rational?

Comment: @cr001: as said, by solving the equation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Solving_equations

Comment: What I got is ${\ln(t)\over t-1}e^{\ln(t)\over t-1}={q\ln(t)\over t-1}$ so ${\ln(t)\over t-1}=W({q\ln(t)\over t-1})$ but there is $t$ inside the $W$ while what we want is only $q$ inside $W$.

Comment: @cr001: read the link carefully.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I start to understand now.

Comment: What do you think about $q<0$ ?

Comment: @lonestudent: just irrelevant.

Comment: Irrelevant. Well, can you find $t\in\mathbb R \setminus {0} $ for $q=-3$ ?

Comment: @lonestudent: read my answer thoroughly.

Answer (score -2):

We have,

$$t-1=a^{t-1}-1, ~ \text{where} ~ a\in\mathbb {Q^{+}}$$

$$\implies a^x=x+1, x=t-1$$

Substitute $a^x=t \implies x\ln a=\ln t $

$$\implies  t=\dfrac {\ln t}{\ln a}+1$$

Substitute $\ln t=u$

$$\implies e^u=\dfrac{u+\ln a}{\ln a}$$

$$\implies e^{u+\ln a}=\dfrac {a}{\ln a}(u+\ln a)$$

$$\implies (u+\ln a)^{-1} e^{u+\ln a}=\dfrac {a}{\ln a}$$

$$\implies  \left((u+\ln a)^{-1} e^{u+\ln a}\right)^{-1}=\dfrac {\ln a}{a}$$

Substitue $z=u+\ln a$

$$\implies -ze^{-z}=-\dfrac {\ln a}{a}$$

$$\implies W(-ze^{-z})=W\left(-\dfrac {\ln a}{ a}\right)$$

$$\implies z=-W\left(-\dfrac {\ln a}{a}\right)$$

If we take the substitutes backwards

$$t=\dfrac{e^z}{a}$$

We have:

$$\implies t=\dfrac{e^{-W\left(-\frac {\ln a}{a}\right)}}{a}$$

So, $a \in\mathbb {Q^{+}}$, where $$\color {gold}{\boxed {\color{blue}{t=\dfrac{e^{-W\left(-\frac {\ln a}{a}\right)}}{a}}}}$$

Thus, your conjecture is not true.

- Here $W(x)$ is a [Lambert function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Lambert%20W,w%20is%20the%20exponential%20function.)

Comment: Downvoters please at least say a valid argument..